# MPLAB X IDE v6.05, Makefile generated by what?

Tags: makefile, mplab-x

I'm working on historic projects developed with MPLAB X IDE v6.05, there are a lot of Makefiles and at the top of many of the files there is a comment:

```
#
# Generated Makefile - do not edit!
```

I'm trying to figure out what it is that generates these Makefiles because I need to change the content.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say who's doing it in one sentence. But I once encountered such a sentence in make files created by older versions of ECLIPSE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).